# How to delay log file creation until Appender fileName is set programmatically for log4j2

Tags: java, xml, log4j, log4j2

I have a project with log4j properties defined in xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <Configuration>
        <Appenders>
            <File name="LogFileAppender" fileName="${sys:logFileName:-default}" append="false">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%d [%t] %p - %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
            </File>
        </Appenders>
    
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="error">
                <AppenderRef ref="LogFileAppender"/>
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

I update the **fileName** value to the correct path in the code before any logging occurs to get the correct output folder.

```
public static void initializeLoggers(String logPath)
{
    // set output paths for log files
    System.setProperty("logFileName", logPath + "PROJECT.log");

    // reconfigure loggers with paths
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext ctx =
            (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    ctx.reconfigure();
}
```

Everything works as expected for the most part. Log files are output to the correct logPath with data written out. However, there is a file called "default" created in the default project directory before we even reach initializeLoggers() because of the call to

```
static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class); // Logging
```

at the top of the code.

I found away to not generate a "default file" by simply leaving the field as blank like so:

> fileName="${sys:logFileName:-}"

But in doing so the code complains and gives errors since the property is null at that specific time.

> 2022-01-19 13:07:51,936 main ERROR The parameter is null: fileName
> 2022-01-19 13:07:51,944 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type
> class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element
> File org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException:
> Arguments given for element File are invalid: field 'fileName' has
> invalid value ''  at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:210)

Is there any way around this so that I can

- not generate an unused "default file"
- not have errors being thrown about null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delay the initialization of Log4j, you need to carefully control the usage of `LogManager.getLogger` and similar methods. For example you should not use a static `Logger` field in your **main** class, but call `LogManager.getLogger` only **after** you initialized logging.

This can be a little tricky to get right, but the system property [`log4j2.loggerContextStacktraceOnStart`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#loggerContextStacktraceOnStart) can help you.

An easier approach is to move the configuration file out of the way of the automatic configuration process, e.g. by calling it `myapp-log4j2.xml`. This way the first configuration will use the default configuration (which uses only a console appender) and you can reconfigure it after you set the appropriate system variables:

```java
  private static final String CONFIG_FILE = "myapp-log4j2.xml";

  public static void initializeLoggers(String logPath) {
    final ClassLoader tccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    final ClassLoader cl = SomeClass.class.getClassLoader();
    final URL resource = tccl != null ? tccl.getResource(CONFIG_FILE)
        : cl != null ? cl.getResource(CONFIG_FILE) : ClassLoader.getSystemResource(CONFIG_FILE);
    if (resource != null) {
      System.setProperty("logFileName", logPath + "PROJECT.log");
      Configurator.reconfigure(resource.toURI());
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, that makes a bit more sense! side note but how can i put myapp-log4j2.xml into a directory? currently it needs to sit on the project level but if i try setting `CONFIG_FILE = "config\\myapp-log4j.xml"` the code does not detect it. i've never used ClassLoaders or URLs before

Comment: note i modified your code to `ClassLoader cl = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();` since getClass cannot be referenced from a static method

Comment: Thanks, I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: do you know of a method to answer my first question in the comments? if not i will do some more digging

Comment: @Barry: classloaders use a forward slash `/` as path separator.

Comment: neither // nor \\ works